# Youtube channel link icon is not showing my website favicon

Tags: html, youtube, favicon

I have a favicon on my website which is working and displaying on all pages. However, when I link my website on my youtube channel, my youtube channel does not show my website favicon, but a globe icon instead:
[image]

It should show the website favicon of the website I link which works if you link instagram, spotify or any other website:
[image]

Comment: [This](https://talotics.com/post/tactics/youtube/channel-link-icons-favicon/)? Google 'link website to youtube favicon'.

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve my issue

Comment: I have the same issue. An image is available under `/favicon.ico`, but it seems that Youtube does not load it or has cached that there is no favicon available.

Comment: I also see caching issues. It appears to cache older versions of a favicon even if you remove and re-add the link. Not sure how long that cache lasts.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have same issue

Comment: Hello, the issue was resolved. It was related to ISP/Youtube caching, so nothing to do with my website. It got fixed after 1 week or so.

Comment: Hi. for this did you had to add the image as an .ico ? or was it working with a png image ?